# Updation not happening in the first click

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am fetching the values from data table to allotted table and name from attendents table. I am able to get values from data on submit but getting name on submitting second time. Here is my sql query code:

```
    $allot = "SELECT id from data ORDER BY id desc";
    $all = mysqli_query($link,$allot);
    $id3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($all);
    $id3 = $id3['id'];
    echo $id3;


    $sql = "INSERT INTO allotted (id,pickup_loc,pickup_ward,drop_loc,drop_ward,task)
    SELECT id,pickup_loc,pickup_ward,drop_loc,drop_ward,task
    FROM data ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 1";


       $query3 = "SELECT attendants_name FROM attendents WHERE id = '$id'";
       $result3 = mysqli_query($link,$query3);
       $id2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3);
       $id2 = $id2['attendants_name'];
       print_r($id2);
       $update_name = "UPDATE allotted SET attendants_name = '$id2' WHERE id = '$id3'";
       $check1 = mysqli_query($link,$update_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$id2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3);

$id2 = $id2['attendants_name'];

print_r($id2);
```

Whats the output you get here? is it a text or an array? please check.

Hope that will work.

Comment: I am getting the output as text but the text is inserting on submitting second time but not on first time

Answer (score 0):

$sql = "INSERT INTO allotted (id,pickup_loc,pickup_ward,drop_loc,drop_ward,task)
        SELECT id,pickup_loc,pickup_ward,drop_loc,drop_ward,task
        FROM data ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 1 ";
        **$al=mysqli_num_rows($sql);
        $insert=mysqli_query($link,$sql);**

I got the answer by executing this query. This query is called first initially only once and now i changed it to calling query every time which solved my problem.

Thank you guys for helping me with your solutions.